# unable to executing android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

when I was compiling my application i am getting **

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared from
loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader [DexPathList[[zip file
"/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar",  zip file
"/data/app/org.commcare.dalvik-1.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.commcare.dalvik-1, 
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

please find my problem and let me know what is the problem with execution...

Comment: Please right click on your project goto build path->configure build path->order and export and select all check box now you can clean and run your project hope it run fine....

Answer (score 0):

Which means `Google Play Partial APK Update Goes Wrong`

You will need to copy the `libstlport_shared.so` file from the libs/armeabi folder into your application's libs/armeabi folder. You can check for that and move the file if it's not present

Comment: already my file is in lib/armeabi folder.i didn't under stand what to do?

Comment: please provide reply for my comment.